# How can I rollback from the last commit in the git

Tags: git

I have accidentally pushed the code in git from visual studio. I want to rollback from this commit from the visual studio itself. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Open a command line (such as `git bash`), `cd` into your project directory and do:

```
git revert HEAD
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to rollback from this commit **from the visual studio itself**

See "[Revert changes in shared commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/undo?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#revert-changes-in-shared-commits)"

> Use **`revert`** to undo the changes made in your commits pushed to shared branches.
>   The revert command creates a new commit that undoes the changes on a previous commit. No history is rewritten in a revert, making it safe to use when working with others.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/vs_revert_changes.png?view=azure-devops]

Then push.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want **roolback a commit** in git you need to use the following command :

```
git revert HEAD  ##to return to the HEAD commit
git push         ##to update you remote repository
```

In several ide, there are an integreted git gui, you can try do this 2 command with the utilities provided by these tools.

There are also other git gui like *Smartgit, GitHub Desktop, Tortoise Git* and so on that provided the same functionality of the classical command line git.

[Smartgit](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/)

[GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)

[Tortoise Git](https://tortoisegit.org/?wb48617274=bWF0dGVvLmJvdHRpY2NpQGxlb25hcmRvY29tcGFueS5jb207OzEyNy4wLjAuMTsxNTc2NzQ2NzgzOzMNRw%20t3lwjd2VagXrFMaesxkw1XV2Om5f%20aCQcm/H1ZnbHBlDg74fQlEq0B6VFLmpI%208ypRkBCuhTnSVDm/2vFQhWR1sdihFes/%20M%20aSlgZheal%20RzZr7nuOIsdKu1cPNARUG3fgCys9N4vhNdT%20ev0ha07h7YgzyAKWEWTmQT)